# Basic of declaration/name indroduction

Tags: c++

OK I had read some article recently which said like :

Every name declared in c++ has type associated with it. e.g

```
int a; //type of a int 
void foo(); //type is void(*)()
class bar; //what is type of bar here then ?
```

Comment: seems everyone knows about it except me )

Comment: `class bar` is a declaration of a type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't have a "type" in the traditional sense, but rather, is a type. While in some languages like Ruby or Objective-C, classes are objects (objects of class `Class`), in C++, classes have no type beyond being a type. They do have an associated `type_info`, but that is not the class itself, rather just some information that must be accessed through `typeid`.

`bar` is not of type `bar`. `bar` is not even an object. Bar is a type, which, as said before, in C++, have no type.

Comment: I had initially thought bar has type bar itself but confused. that's why the question )

Comment: foo isn't object too but it has type, right ?

Comment: @HolyKiller: Not exactly. That definition of foo is not an object either, but does have a type. Classes, unlike functions, don't really exist at runtime in the same way the functions do.

Comment: function also don't exist at runtime , they becomes simply sequence of instruction .Language concept has nothing to do with runtime concept I mean to say

Comment: @HolyKiller: The point is, classes have no type. Period.